# What program should I use to edit a 1 GB Matlab code

Tags: windows-7, memory, notepad++, matlab, memory-leaks

I just used Matlab's Neural Network Toolbox to create some functions (`.m` files that return matrices based on the matrix you put in). I now need to edit the code a little, to modify some details.

But these codes are so large, almost 1 gigabyte, that Matlab tells me it can't open this, because it doesn't have enough memory. (That's what is says in a popup, after trying for a few minutes and printing the error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` seven times. And this is after I increased the Java heap space memory to 8 GB and restarted Matlab.)

Aware that Notepad++ is a light program designed for writing code in languages such as Matlab, I tried opening it in Notepad++, but it instantly told me, that's too big.

Are these programs not designed to use 64 bits - not even 30 bits - to navigate the bytes of text files? Is there a program that is? What might be a way around this?

Comment: couldn't you google your question first and state if there was any issue. Is this your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159521/text-editor-to-open-big-giant-huge-large-text-files

Comment: @barlop Thanks, I think that solves my problem. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Even if they are 64-bit versions of those programs, because of the lack of system memory (by the fact you cannot open a 1GB file), won't make any difference if you is 32-Bit or 64-Bit

Comment: @Ramhound The system has 32 GB of memory, and I don't think more than 24 GB was in use at any time. (Less than 15 when I got this error.) It's clearly a problem with the algorithms of the software.

Comment: 1GB is nothing, a 32-bit process can open a 3GB file, on a 64-bit OS (and 32-bit.  something else is going on, what command, did you use to increase the heap size?

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a difference between heap space and swap size?

Comment: @Ramhound In the Matlab GUI, on the Home tab, under Environment, I clicked Preferences, and in the menu on the window that came up I went to MATLAB>General>Java Heap Memory, and then clicked and dragged the bar all the way to 8,168 MB. It notifies you when you do that of the need to restart Matlab, and I did. I go there now, and it says the heap size is 8,168 MB.

Comment: what did you use in the end?

Comment: @barlop SlickEdit looks nice, though the fact that I need to make a lot of choices of exactly what I want before seeing the price looks scary. I found an error I'd made, and now the files are only in the tens of MB, so for now, Notepad++ is where I'll turn to when Matlab doesn't work or is slow. Thanks!

Comment: @Post169 i'd be interested if editpad lite can cope with it. It's a free program and it's not difficult to use like gvim/vim